# Module parse failed: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: parsing, next.js, module, max, call

I'm getting this error from a function I created for dynamic and flexible styling on any type of property used in dynamic components and styling with **Styled Components**.

This is the **useMediaQuery** function:

```
export const useMediaQuery = (arr: Array<string | number>, name: string) => {
  if (!arr || !name) return;

  const query = new Array<string>();

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    query.push(`@media (min-width: ${
      queryBreakpoints[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1]
        ? typeof queryBreakpoints[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1] === "number"
          ? `${queryBreakpoints[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1]}px`
          : queryBreakpoints[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1]
        : `${0}px`
    }) and (max-width: ${
      typeof queryBreakpoints[i] === "number"
        ? `${queryBreakpoints[i]}px`
        : queryBreakpoints[i]
    }) {
        ${name}: ${
      typeof arr[i] === "number" ? `${arr[i]}px` : arr[i] ? arr[i] : "auto"
    };
    }`);
  }

  query.push(`@media (min-width: ${
    queryBreakpoints[arr.length === 1 ? 0 : arr.length - 1]
      ? typeof queryBreakpoints[arr.length === 1 ? 0 : arr.length - 1] ===
        "number"
        ? `${queryBreakpoints[arr.length === 1 ? 0 : arr.length - 1]}px`
        : queryBreakpoints[arr.length === 1 ? 0 : arr.length - 1]
      : `${0}px`
  }) {
        ${name}: ${
    typeof arr[arr.length === 1 ? 0 : arr.length - 1] === "number"
      ? `${arr[arr.length === 1 ? 0 : arr.length - 1]}px`
      : arr[arr.length === 1 ? 0 : arr.length - 1]
      ? arr[arr.length === 1 ? 0 : arr.length - 1]
      : "auto"
  }};`);

  return `& { ${query.join("")} }`;
};
```

This is the component in question **Box**:

```
 ${({ w }) => {
    if (typeof w === "object") {
      return useMediaQuery(w, "width");
    } else {
      return `width: ${typeof w === "number" ? `${w}px` : w ? w : "100%"};`;
    }
  }}
  ${({ maxWidth }) => {
    if (typeof maxWidth === "object") {
      return useMediaQuery(maxWidth, "max-width");
    } else {
      return `max-width: ${
        typeof maxWidth === "number"
          ? `${maxWidth}px`
          : maxWidth
          ? maxWidth
          : "unset"
      };`;
    }
  }}
  ${({ h }) => {
    if (typeof h === "object") {
      return useMediaQuery(h, "height");
    } else {
      return `height: ${typeof h === "number" ? `${h}px` : h ? h : "100%"};`;
    }
  }}
  ${({ maxHeight }) => {
    if (typeof maxHeight === "object") {
      return useMediaQuery(maxHeight, "max-height");
    } else {
      return `max-height: ${
        typeof maxHeight === "number"
          ? `${maxHeight}px`
          : maxHeight
          ? maxHeight
          : "unset"
      };`;
    }
  }}
```

It is too big to be placed here in one piece but the logic for all types of style attributes is the same, this function in question is called a total of **25 times** among the components that use it, my question was why this error be happening since it doesn't create an infinite looping, even **changing its structure to use a type of Object it keeps giving the same error**, would someone know how to explain and guide me? I've done a lot of research but they all lead me to a completely different problem that only deals with infinite loops.

I tried to switch the function structure logic from Array to a Static Object but the error still persists, I still get the same message: *Module parse failed: Maximum call stack size exceeded*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the error persisted due to the number of calls to the function, whether it was static or looping, I decided to deal with the properties in the Styled sheet and that way it was solved!

Result:

```
${({ w }) => {
    if (typeof w === "object") {
      const query = new Array<string>();
      const name = "width";

      for (let i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
        query.push(`@media (min-width: ${
          queryBreakpoints[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1]
            ? typeof queryBreakpoints[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1] === "number"
              ? `${queryBreakpoints[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1]}px`
              : queryBreakpoints[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1]
            : `${0}px`
        }) and (max-width: ${
          typeof queryBreakpoints[i] === "number"
            ? `${queryBreakpoints[i]}px`
            : queryBreakpoints[i]
        }) {
            ${name}: ${
          typeof w[i] === "number" ? `${w[i]}px` : w[i] ? w[i] : "auto"
        };
        }`);
      }

      query.push(`@media (min-width: ${
        queryBreakpoints[w.length === 1 ? 0 : w.length - 1]
          ? typeof queryBreakpoints[w.length === 1 ? 0 : w.length - 1] ===
            "number"
            ? `${queryBreakpoints[w.length === 1 ? 0 : w.length - 1]}px`
            : queryBreakpoints[w.length === 1 ? 0 : w.length - 1]
          : `${0}px`
      }) {
            ${name}: ${
        typeof w[w.length === 1 ? 0 : w.length - 1] === "number"
          ? `${w[w.length === 1 ? 0 : w.length - 1]}px`
          : w[w.length === 1 ? 0 : w.length - 1]
          ? w[w.length === 1 ? 0 : w.length - 1]
          : "auto"
      }};`);

      return `& { ${query.join("")} }`;
    } else {
      return `width: ${typeof w === "number" ? `${w}px` : w ? w : "100%"};`;
    }
  }}
```